# Table border is missing in some browsers .(border-collapse)

Tags: html, css, html-table

For the following table structure table border is showing in some browsers, and in some browsers it is not showing.

```css
.test-table, table.test-table th, table.test-table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px !important;
} 
.test-td{
  border-bottom:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="test-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Heading 1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Heading 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test </td>
            <td>Test </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="test-td">Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="common-heading">Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See the below screenshot of table in browsers:

Firefox table

[image]

Chrome table

[image]

The Firefox table structure is the correct structure, but in Chrome it is not showing properly. What is wrong in this code? How to make the table structure same in every browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `rowspan=4` for that Cell like below

```css
.test-table, table.test-table th, table.test-table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px !important;
} 
.test-td{

}
```

```html
   

<table class="test-table">
  <tbody><tr>
   <td colspan="2">Heading 1</td> 
    <td rowspan="2">Heading 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test </td>
 <td>Test </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2">Test</td> 
   <td rowspan="4"  class="test-td">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
 <td>Test</td>
  
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Test</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="common-heading">Test</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375975/how-to-redirect-all-mobile-folder-files-to-main-folder-file-using-htacess

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution might be it help.

You have to add rowspan=4

[`Here is the example`](https://codepen.io/hardenrahul/pen/boyZmY)